# set default gap to 0 in MiG Layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, miglayout

Is there a way to  make the default gap between components of all layouts ever to be created in a specific program to be 0?

Is there any way to do it?
If not, is there at least a way to do it on a layout-level (new MigLayout("gaptozero");)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `MigLayout("insets 0");`

EDIT:

To fix for gaps (see comments) you can simply write: `MigLayout("gap 0");` Or, gapx and gapy.

All this comes from: http://migcalendar.com/miglayout/cheatsheet.html

Comment: @Karlovsky if this is the answer, your question is badly worded: insets (aka: just like "normal" insets, that is the space around the container) != gap (aka: the space between components in the container)

Comment: He guessed what I wanted (to make distance between components zero), and I was unaware that insets weren't zero by default so I thought that the gaps were messing me up. But it's not answer to the question, that is correct.

Comment: Is there a way do do it on a global scale?

something like `MigLayoutDefaults.setDefaultGap(gap 0!);` (same goes for insets), so I don't have to write everytime I create a new instance of the manager?

Comment: I don't have experience with it but try here: http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/mavensite/apidocs/net/miginfocom/layout/PlatformDefaults.html